# MDX Doesn't show last version of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx

i need a little help to figure out a problem i have in MDX. I want to show the last version per period of a measure even if the value is NULL. But my code show me the last non empty version.

**Example :**

[image: My problem]

Here is my code : (the visible measure in the tables is MNY_ENCOURS)

```
SCOPE([DIM Version].[VCR BK Version].[All]);
    [Measures].[MNY_AA_Total] = tail(filter([DIM Version].[VCR BK Version].[All], not isempty([Measures].[MNY_AA_Total])));
    [Measures].[MNY_ENCOURS] = tail(filter([DIM Version].[VCR BK Version].[All], not isempty([Measures].[MNY_ENCOURS])));
    [Measures].[MNY_Flottement] = tail(filter([DIM Version].[VCR BK Version].[All], not isempty([Measures].[MNY_Flottement])));
    [Measures].[MNY_Montant_Cale] = tail(filter([DIM Version].[VCR BK Version].[All], not isempty([Measures].[MNY_Montant_Cale])));
    [Measures].[MNY_VARIATION_ENCOURS] = tail(filter([DIM Version].[VCR BK Version].[All], not isempty([Measures].[MNY_VARIATION_ENCOURS])));
    [Measures].[V FCT Collecte Count] = tail(filter([DIM Version].[VCR BK Version].[All], not isempty([Measures].[V FCT Collecte Count])));
    [Measures].[CONFI_FLUX] = tail(filter([DIM Version].[VCR BK Version].[All], not isempty([Measures].[CONFI_FLUX])));
    [Measures].[CONFI_STOCKS] = tail(filter([DIM Version].[VCR BK Version].[All], not isempty([Measures].[CONFI_STOCKS])));
    [Measures].[Declarant_Distinct_Count] = tail(filter([DIM Version].[VCR BK Version].[All], not isempty([Measures].[Declarant_Distinct_Count])));
    [Measures].[MNY_FLUX_CALCULE] = tail(filter([DIM Version].[VCR BK Version].[All], not isempty([Measures].[MNY_FLUX_CALCULE])));
    [Measures].[PART_FLUX_Trimestriel]=tail(filter([DIM Version].[VCR BK Version].[All], not isempty([Measures].[PART_FLUX_Trimestriel])));
    [Measures].[PART_STOCKS]= tail(filter([DIM Version].[VCR BK Version].[All], not isempty([Measures].[PART_STOCKS])));                  
END SCOPE;
```

Can you please help me ? Thank you

Comment: what if you remove the filter to include all empty values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I had it this way :

`iif([DIM Version].[VCR BK Version].currentmember is [DIM Version].[VCR BK Version].[All],
SUM(TAIL(NonEmptyCrossjoin([DIM Version].[VCR BK Version].MEMBERS,{[DIM Periode].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember})).item(0),[Measures].[MNY_ENCOURS])
,[Measures].[MNY_ENCOURS]);`

Answer (score 1):

Why not just move from this pattern for each measure:

```
...
[Measures].[MNY_ENCOURS] 
  = TAIL(
      FILTER(
        [DIM Version].[VCR BK Version].[All]
      , not isempty([Measures].[MNY_ENCOURS])
    )
...
```

to a tuple, like the following, for each:

```
...
[Measures].[MNY_ENCOURS] 
  = (
      tail([DIM Version].[VCR BK Version].[All].MEMBERS).ITEM(0).ITEM(0)
     ,[Measures].[MNY_ENCOURS]
    )
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this doesn't work because when "Version" is selected in the columns it doesnt show me all the versions but just the last one instead.